# Converting $\rm W/m2/sr/nm$ to $\rm kR/nm$ for any wavelength

Tags: optics, units, spectroscopy, wavelength, si-units

I have atmospheric spectra given in W/m2/sr/nm units and wavelength in nm. I want to convert W/m2/sr/nm to kilo Rayleigh/nm (kR/nm) for any wavelength.

I tried the following method from this paper: https://opg.optica.org/ao/abstract.cfm?URI=ao-13-9-2160.

I also wanted to know what method I should use to get the brightness (kR) value of specific emission peaks, as I want to see its vertical distribution with altitude (Brightness (kR) vs Altitude).

Comment: Voting to reopen. Yet another abuse of the catch-all "homework-like" closing reason.