# How to convert $\rm W/m2/sr/nm$ to $\rm kR/nm$

Tags: optics, units, spectroscopy, si-units

How do I convert spectral radiance $\rm W/m2/sr/nm$ to $\rm kR/nm$?

I tried the following method from this paper: https://opg.optica.org/ao/abstract.cfm?URI=ao-13-9-2160

Comment: Repost of [Converting $\rm W/m2/sr/nm$ to $\rm kR/nm$ for any wavelength](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/797544/converting-rm-w-m2-sr-nm-to-rm-kr-nm-for-any-wavelength).